# Create gradle task which runs for all flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I've been looking on the interwebs how to create a custom gradle task, which will run an existing command for all Flavors.

I have an android App which currently has 10 flavors (including default). Which all use the same code they're just differently styled and named for clients.

I was wondering if I could create a task where I could run tasks for every single app.

I have different cases for this, installing on device, pushing to Crashlytics Beta etc.

In the future we might be having 20 apps which would be nice if they'd be pushable to testers at once for example, but I can't really find a simple solution for this.